# drupal global variable

Tags: drupal, global

where is the drupal  global variable in ,it's say in developer/global.php.but in drupal install file,i can't find this file. what's the difference of the global variable and the avariable variables in page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php......  where is the declaration  of the template avariable variables in.thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables for template files are declared in template preprocess functions. [This page](http://drupal.org/node/173880) in the Drupal theming guide contains a [flowchart describing the flow](http://drupal.org/files/theme_flow_6_1.pdf) of Drupal's [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6) function. For every template, the variables pass every preprocess function that matches the appropriate naming scheme.

For instance, for page.tpl.php, Drupal will first run [template_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/6) and [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6). Next, if some module contains the function somemodule_preprocess_page(), and/or if your custom contains yourtheme_preprocess_page(), those functions will be run as well. Every preprocess function can alter and add variables for the page.tpl.php template. When all preprocess functions have finished, the variables are passed to page.tpl.php.

Answer (score -1):

There is a file called [settings.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites--default--default.settings.php/6/source) which may be what you're looking for.

Alternatively, if you'd like the owners of the site to be able to modify the variables without them having to change the source code, you can create a variable in the admin page of one of your modules, which can then be accessed at any point your application using drupal's [`variable_get()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6).

Comment: While it's true what you say, I don't think that this is an appropriate answer to the question. Both the settings.php file and the variable_set/variable_get mechanism are not meant to make variables available to template files.

Comment: variable_set() and variable_get() will clear the variable cache each time it is called and cause a significant performance hit.